# permission enable

Tags: 7, users

I have created new user/role for my user.
What permission I need to enable for my user to let them access the Admin->Structure->Pages ?

I want this "Structure->Pages" enable in my user page
[image: I want this "Structure->Pages" enable in my user page]

what permission I need to enable to let my user to access the "Structure->Pages"?

extra question, what permission I need to enable to let my user to access the "People->Newsletter subscription"?

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign its permission in admin(path->**`http://example.com/admin/people/permissions`**)
e.g you have create a new role **testrole**

[image]

You just need to tick mark the checkbox under your newrole (**testrole**).
Now it will be accessible to this role.

Comment: It works, thank you. One more question, how to enable "people->newsletter subscription" for my user, the image I will post at question?

Comment: Do you want to show newsletter subscription form to this role user?

Comment: Ya, I want to let my user to view all the newletters' subscriber. Therefore, I want the "People->Newsletters subscription" button available in the user page. currently the button is not available in the user page yet, I think is the permission problem. *I have posted clearer image*

Comment: Thanks Raj10, I found out the solution at https://www.drupal.org/node/993080